# How do I resize buttons on windowbuilder eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder, eclipse-neon

So I just installed window builder for eclipse neon, and when I added some components to the frame; I wasn't able to resize them, I was limited to north,south,east,west, and center. Any ideas on how to resize these components?

Comment: Layouts. You need to research the different SWT layouts.

Comment: Don't use the IDE to create the form. You are leaning how to use the IDE and not how to use Swing. Instead code the frame yourself. Then your code will still be maintainable even if you move to a different IDE in the future. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples.

Comment: @ppeterka Oh yea thanks! almost forgot that I could set the layout to null, thanks for reminding me! :)

Answer (score 0):

this problem is related to absolute layout. What you need to do is click on `"absolute layout" (Palette>Layouts)` and then click on the `frame` and it's ok